# CakePhp with xampp

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I am trying to execute my first application in cakephp, but it's giving an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache
engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:166 Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(136): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/app/Config/core.php(336):
Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(78):
include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(171):
Configure::bootstrap(true) #4
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/app/webroot/index.php(92):
include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #5 {main} thrown in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 166
```

and two warnings

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to
File cache in /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on
line 310

Warning: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not
writable in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on
line 337
```

Pleas give me any solution to do my first application with cakephp.

Comment: Try to add write permission to all folder under APP/tmp directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache folder is not writable according to warning.

open terminal, run `sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo -R`

Plus, you should reconfigure file permissions, like 775, in real productions.

Comment: Could you please check the current folder permission of app/temp by the command "ll /opt/lampp/htdocs/CakeTooDoo/app/tmp"? see if the permission is drwxrwxwrx for your've previously set permission by chmod 777.

Comment: @Hamender, I dont understand why my anwser didnt work? Can you explain here?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a permissive ownership:

```
chmod -R 777 app/tmp
```

A better method is to change group ownership of tmp and everthing below it to www-data ( or whatever group your apache server runs in ) with 'chgrp -R www-data tmp' followed by '`chmod -R 774 tmp`' This makes tmp read/write for you and the www-data group but readonly for everyone else

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: will you please vote up my answer so it would be very use full to other in future if some has some issue. and that would be glad for me to help you.